# Biblatex 3.3 name formatting, just year shown

Tags: biblatex, biber

I tryed to adapt my bibmacros to the new version of Biblatex but now when I use them, just the year is shown in my citation.

My bibmacro looks like this:

```
\newbibmacro{name:normalfall}{% Normalfall: 1,4,5,8
   \textbf{\namepartfamily}  % #1->\namepartfamily, #2->\namepartfamilyi
   \textbf{\namepartgiveni}   % #3->\namepartgiven,  #4->\namepartgiveni
   \namepartprefix % #5->\namepartprefix, #6->\namepartprefixi
   \namepartsuffixi % #7->\namepartsuffix, #8->\namepartsuffixi
}
```

And I use it with:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{% Bibliographie
\nameparts{#1}
  \ifnum\value{uniquename}=0 % Normalfall
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:normalfall}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:normalfall2}}%
  \fi
```

On the pages under the text, just the year and not the authors are written.

It should look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

I hope I wrote understandable what my problem is.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

I am using a prepared test file of my university where everything worked but the citing.

Example for the .bib-file:

```
@Book{Test,
  Title                    = {TestTitle},
  Author                   = {Testauthor, N.},
  Year                     = {2007},
  Publisher                = {TestPublisher},

  Address                  = {TestAdress},
  Owner                    = {Testowner},
  Timestamp                = {2015.01.04}
}
```

I want to use it in the text with:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 

\usepackage[                % Biblatex
  backend=biber,
  bibstyle=_dhbw_authoryear,
  citestyle=authoryear,     
  uniquename=true, useprefix=true,
  bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\input{includes/_dhbw_biblatex-config.tex}

\bibliography{includes/literatur-datenbank.bib}

\begin{document}

Testauthor\footcite{Test} here is more text.

\end{document}
```

The _dhbw_biblatex-config.tex consists of the newbibmacro and the DeclareNameFormat that is written at the beginning of my question.

I hope this helps, if not, correct me and ask for more information please.

---

Edit:
I don't know if I should delete the old part, I will now try to give all needed information.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 

\usepackage[                % Biblatex
  backend=biber,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  citestyle=authoryear,     
  uniquename=true, useprefix=true,
  bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\input{includes/_dhbw_biblatex-config.tex}

\bibliography{includes/literatur-datenbank.bib}

\begin{document}

Testauthor\footcite{Test} here is more text.

\end{document}
```

The included literature database (literatur-datenbank.bib) is:

```
@Book{Test,
  Title                    = {TestTitle},
  Author                   = {Testauthor, N.},
  Year                     = {2007},
  Publisher                = {TestPublisher},

  Address                  = {TestAdress},
  Owner                    = {Testowner},
  Timestamp                = {2015.01.04}
}
```

And the _dhbw_biblatex-config.tex is:

```
\newbibmacro{name:normalfallZ}{% complete first name: 1, ,5,8
   \textbf{\namepartfamily}  % #1->\namepartfamily, #2->\namepartfamilyi
   \textbf{}   % #3->\namepartgiven,  #4->\namepartgiveni
   \namepartprefix % #5->\namepartprefix, #6->\namepartprefixi
   \namepartsuffixi % #7->\namepartsuffix, #8->\namepartsuffixi
   }

%Order of authors
%   
% http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,80448.html#80448
% Argumente: siehe http://texwelt.de/blog/modifizieren-eines-biblatex-stils/

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{% 
  \ifnum\value{uniquename}=0 % 
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:normalfallZ}}

  \fi

 }
```

How I said, just the year is shown on the bottom of my PDF, not the author.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your problem would be easier to understand (for me at least) if you could give [a full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that we can compile and play around with. Do you use Biber? How do the macros you show us there work/how are they called?

Comment: Maybe what you want can also be achieved without poking around in the innards of the name macros. What do you want to get?

Comment: How would the `DeclareNameFormat` come into play? As far as I can see, this has effect on just the bibliography, not citations -- right? The citestyle is a standard style, and I don't have the bibstyle (is it a customized one?). So I used option  `style=authoryear` -- but of course that prints "Testauthor
2007." as footnote. A working MWE (possibly with a link to the non-standard style files) would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: With your MWE I can't reproduce the problem you show us in the screenshots (I had to replace `_dhbw_authoryear` by `authoryear` and `\input{includes/_dhbw_biblatex-config.tex}` by the snippets you gave above), the problem does not come from what you have shown us so far. Please create an MWE that we can run on our machines out of the box that also reproduces the problem.

Comment: All I can say at this point is that while `name:normalfall` looks a bit fishy, it seems to work just fine. Note that the code you have shown us so far would normally only affect the bibliography and not the citations (of course I can't be sure about your custom style, but normally `default` would not apply to citations).

Comment: The `name:normalfallZ` of also looks quite fishy. If this is a "template" (or ready-made style for your university) you should definitely contact the author and ask for an update. (I wrote http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,80448.html#80448, but you will find that the code here bears little resemblance to what you find there.)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the name format misses the call to  `\nameparts{#1}`. This command populates  the various parts of the name (for each parts, it generates two value, the full and the initial one).

Thus the `\DeclareNameFormat` definition should be changed as follows

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \nameparts{#1}%  <== add this line
  \ifnum\value{uniquename}=0 % 
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:normalfallZ}}
  \fi
 }
```

By the ways the use of  the various conditionals is unclear, thus  the definition can simply be:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{% 
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:normalfallZ}%
 }
```

Comment: In `biblatex` >= 3.4 `\nameparts` is a no-op and thus unnecessary, but in 3.3 it is indeed needed. Indeed the logic doesn't seem to be thought trough at all. Note that in `biblatex.def` the `name:` macros take the name parts as arguments and don't call `\nampart...` themselves (but that is probably more a matter of taste than anything).

Comment: Thank you so much! :) It works. The only problem is, that there is now a lot of whitespace. Could you imagine why?

Comment: The spaces come from the spaces between the name parts commands and %. In your  definition you add a space after the family name, a space after the empty bold and so on.